# Showing status codes of URLs as 0 in this PHP code

Tags: php, html, http, url

In this php code, the HTTP Status Code is not correctly shown instead it is showing 0.

The below code gets a link from the user and check the specific URL and also check for some directories inside it, to check whether it's status code.

The directory links to be attached are saved in a .txt file.

The code is inside a loop because we have to read the txt file line by line and print each of it's status code.

**Here Is The Code of Homepage For The User**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dirbuster</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="" action="dirsearch.php" method="post">
      <h1>Enter or paste the URL: </h1>
      <p>End the URL with a "/"</p>
      <input type="text" name="thelink">
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Here is the PHP Code To Show The Status Codes**

```
<?php

function dirSearch() {
  $file = fopen("wordlist1.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");

  // Output a line of the file until the end is reached
    while(!feof($file)) {
      $link = $_POST["thelink"];
      $extension = fgets($file);
      $url = $_POST["thelink"].$extension;
      $ch = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);    // FETCHING HEADER
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);    // DON'T  FETCH BODY
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
      $output = curl_exec($ch);
      $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
      curl_close($ch);

      echo $url;
      echo " <b>Response Code</b>:->> <b><u>$httpcode</u></b> <br><br>";
    }
    fclose($file);
}

dirSearch();

?>
```

**The text file:** [wordlist1.txt](http://localhost/HackersArena/dirfinder/wordlist1.txt)

I need this code to show the correct Status Codes of each URL with the attached directories from the txt file.

Comment: what is the response are u getting?

Comment: On failure the function `curl_getinfo` will return 0 (false).

Comment: @KOTIOS I am getting 0 for all the URLs except the homepage.

Comment: You need to check if there was a curl error before you check the http status. For example if there was a DNS error then no point checking for HTTP status code.